# group data using a vector of keys in JavaScript, add empty array where key is not in data

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, lookup, reduce

I'd like to use this vector of keys

```
const vec_of_vals = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

to group and filter an array of objects

```
const data = [
  {grade: "one"},
  {grade: "one"},
  {grade: "one"},
  {grade: "two"},
  {grade: "four"},
  {grade: "four"},
  {grade: "four"},
  {grade: "four"},
  {grade: "five"},
  {grade: "five"},
  {grade: "five"},
  {grade: "six"}
]
```

And I've found posts that can help me to do this, **but they don't include an empty `"three"` array which is in my initial `vec_of_vals`**

#### Here's what I've tried

```
function groupByKey(array, key) {
  return array.reduce((hash, obj) => {
    if (obj[key] === undefined) return hash;
    return Object.assign(hash, {
      [obj[key]]: (hash[obj[key]] || []).concat(obj),
    });
  }, {});
}

groupByKey(
  data.filter((x) => vec_of_vals.includes(x.grade)),
  "grade"
);
```

But this wont give me the empty `three` array AND it doesn't keep the original order of my data!. As a visual here is my desired output:

## Desired Output

```
let desired_output = {
  "one" : [
    {grade: "one"},
    {grade: "one"},
  ],
  "two" : [
    {grade: "two"},
  ],
  "three" : [],
  "four" : [
    {grade: "four"},
    {grade: "four"},
    {grade: "four"},
    {grade: "four"}
  ]
}
```

How do I change the `groupByKey` function to not only group by `grade` but insert any missing grades and remove any grades that are not in the original key as well as maintain the order of the original `vec_of_vals`?

Comment: added a more verbose but faster solution and a benchmark of the two

Comment: @MayaGans... The Op might have a look at another, late provided, answer/solution which covers the OP's requirements in every aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array::reduce()` on your result grades:

```js
const grades = 'abcd'.split('');
const data = [
        { grade: "a" }, { grade: "a" }, { grade: "a" }, { grade: "b" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "e" }, { grade: "e" }, { grade: "e" }, { grade: "f" }
    ];

const grouped = grades.reduce((grouped, key) => (grouped[key] = data.filter(({grade}) => grade === key)) && grouped, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped));
```

Or you could iterate your data array (which is twice faster):

```js
const grades = 'abcd'.split('');
const data = [
        { grade: "a" }, { grade: "a" }, { grade: "a" }, { grade: "b" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "e" }, { grade: "e" }, { grade: "e" }, { grade: "f" }
    ];

const grouped = grades.reduce((grouped, grade) => (grouped[grade] = []) && grouped, {});

data.forEach(item => grouped[item.grade]?.push(item));

console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped));
```

And the benchmark:
[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1">

    const grades = 'abcd'.split('');

    const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Array.from({ length: 300000 }).reduce(arr => arr.push(...[
        { grade: "a" }, { grade: "a" }, { grade: "a" }, { grade: "b" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "e" }, { grade: "e" }, { grade: "e" }, { grade: "f" }
    ]) && arr, [])));

    // @benchmark reducing grades and filtering data

    grades.reduce((grouped, key) => (grouped[key] = data.filter(({ grade }) => grade === key)) && grouped, {});

    // @benchmark iterating data array

    const grouped = grades.reduce((grouped, grade) => (grouped[grade] = []) && grouped, {});

    data.forEach(item => grouped[item.grade]?.push(item));
    grouped;


</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible and pretty straightforward approach would be based on two single  [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) tasks.

First one reduces the `data` array into an object which groups and collects the data items each by its `grade`-value ...

```
const gradeCollection = data
  .reduce((collection, dataItem) => {

    const { grade } = dataItem;
    (collection[grade] ??= []).push(dataItem);

    return collection;
  }, {});
```

The final result already can be computed from both, the also provided grade-precedence list (what the OP calls *"vector of keys"* or `vec_of_vals`) and the just processed `gradeCollection`.

In order to align the `result` object's key-value pairs (entries) with the grade-values of the already mentioned `gradePrecedenceList` (formerly known as `vec_of_vals`) one does `reduce` the latter, creating with each iteration an entry where the key equals the current `grade`-value and the value gets looked up from the before created `gradeCollection` by the same `grade`-value. In case of an unsuccessful lookup one would assign an empty array instead.

```
const result = gradePrecedenceList
  .reduce((collection, grade) => {

    collection[grade] = gradeCollection[grade] ?? [];
    return collection;
  }, {});
```

... executable example code which does prove the above said ...

```js
const data = [
  {grade: "one"},
  {grade: "one"},
  {grade: "one"},
  {grade: "two"},
  {grade: "four"},
  {grade: "four"},
  {grade: "four"},
  {grade: "four"},
  {grade: "five"},
  {grade: "five"},
  {grade: "five"},
  {grade: "six"}
];
const gradePrecedenceList = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

const gradeCollection = data
  .reduce((collection, dataItem) => {

    const { grade } = dataItem;
    (collection[grade] ??= []).push(dataItem);

    return collection;
  }, {});

const result = gradePrecedenceList
  .reduce((collection, grade) => {

    collection[grade] = gradeCollection[grade] ?? [];
    return collection;
  }, {});

console.log({ result });
console.log({ gradeCollection });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

And out of interest and for fun ***Alexander Nenashev's*** benchmark test running additionally the above implementation of ***"reduce twice"*** ...

```html
<script benchmark data-count="10">

    const grades = 'abcd'.split('');

    const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Array.from({ length: 300000 }).reduce(arr => arr.push(...[
        { grade: "a" }, { grade: "a" }, { grade: "a" }, { grade: "b" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "d" }, { grade: "e" }, { grade: "e" }, { grade: "e" }, { grade: "f" }
    ]) && arr, [])));

    // @benchmark reducing grades and filtering data

    grades.reduce((grouped, key) => (grouped[key] = data.filter(({ grade }) => grade === key)) && grouped, {});

    // @benchmark iterating data array

    const grouped = grades.reduce((grouped, grade) => (grouped[grade] = []) && grouped, {});

    data.forEach(item => grouped[item.grade]?.push(item));
    grouped;

    // @benchmark reduce twice

    const gradeCollection = data
      .reduce((collection, dataItem) => {

        const { grade } = dataItem;
        (collection[grade] ??= []).push(dataItem);

        return collection;
      }, {});

    grades
      .reduce((collection, grade) => {

        collection[grade] = gradeCollection[grade] ?? [];
        return collection;
      }, {});

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```